# Find user who has no post in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

This the the database relation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I come across a functionality where I want to query all the users who don't have any posts yet. I know that we can do this with something like this:

```
users = User.all
users.each do |user|
  unless user.posts.any?
    # do something when user don't have any post.
  end
end
```

However, I wonder if there is any way to optimize this by using one query only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This results in a single query which fetches all users who don't have posts yet:

```
User.includes(:posts).references(:posts).where('posts.id IS NULL')
```

Another solution is this:

```
User.where('NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM posts WHERE user_id = users.id)')
```

Since this is a rather complex query to use everywhere, you can place this inside a named scope in `User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :without_posts, -> { where('NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM posts WHERE user_id = users.id)') }
end
```

Now you can use this scope elsewhere in your application:

```
User.without_posts
```

Comment: Note: First one doesn't work with PostgreSQL (returns no results), but the `NOT EXISTS` with sub-query works nicely.

Comment: A bit more Rails-esque way might be `User.includes(:posts).where(posts: {id: nil}).references(:posts)`. This should address any DB specific issues, the hash will be dealt with at the db adapter level (I believe).

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like

```
User.joins(posts).where("count(posts.id) = 0")
```

Which returns all users that have 0 posts.

Comment: It seems like this won't work in Postgres though: `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

with rails 6.1, even simpler:

```rb
User.where.missing(:posts)
```