# Ecto/Elixir/Phoenix - Fetch records with no associated record

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have these schemas:

```
  schema "players" do
    field :email, :string
    
    has_many :profiles, MyApp.Profile
    has_many :worlds, through: [:profiles, :world]
  end
```

```
  schema "worlds" do
    field :name, :string
    
    has_many :profiles, MyApp.Profile
    has_many :players, through: [:profiles, :player]
  end
```

```
  schema "settings" do
    field :mode, :string
    
    belongs_to :player, MyApp.Player
    belongs_to :world, MyApp.World
  end
```

All players are supposed to have one settings in each world they create by default. But due to logical errors in our code, some players didn't have settings in some world.

Now I'm trying to find those `players` who don't have existing `settings` record in some world so I can create default settings for them using a seeder.

I've tried workarounds like this:

```
query = from profile in Profile

query
|> Repo.all()
|> Enum.each(fn profile ->
  case get_settings(profile.player_id, profile.world_id) do
    nil ->
      create_settings(profile.player_id, profile.world_id)

    _ ->
      :ok
  end
end)
```

It works but I want to avoid using the case statement. It costs a lot of database work.
Is there any way to fetch those `players` with no existing `settings` record in some `worlds` using a query?

Comment: Do you have a sql query that returns the results you need? I guess you could do a full join on the players and worlds and filter out those records with a matching profile. Honestly I would just have my service return default values when a database lookup misses instead of cramming multiple (hundreds? thousands?) of default profile records into your profile table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Ecto.Query.join/5`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html?#join/5) and [`Ecto.Query.subquery/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html?#subquery/2) more or less like

```rb
subquery =
  from profile in Profile,
    join: player in Player,
    on: player.id == profile.player_id,
    join: world in World,
    on: world.id == profile.world_id

query =
  from setting in Settings,
    join: profile in subquery(subquery),
    on: setting.player_id == profile.player_id and
        setting.world_id == profile.world_id
```

or, even easier, you might directly join settings to profiles on `player_id` and `world_id`.

The latter reveals that you actually have a design flaw. Settings and profiles are basically the same entity, represented twice. That’s why you have inconsistency. Enrich profiles with whatever fields in settings and get rid of settings at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see, there is a design flaw. I'm thinking of redesigning settings table and associate it with profiles table instead of worlds and players. I've tried your example, and I got every existing settings record. What I'm trying to fetch are the players who don't have existing settings record in some worlds.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813171/find-user-who-has-no-post-in-rails) question is quite similar to mine. I'm trying to convert the answer in elixir with Ecto fragment, but still no luck. Maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Use `outer_join` or like, I cannot test it without a schema but the approach described above is correct.